# How to send parameters on AWK to replace a parameter. Unix Korn Shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, replace, parameters

I'm trying to replace a parameter to change a value when the AWK is used to search for a string in a file.

is this possible? I'm doing this.

```
DisplayMessage()
{
  ##Parameter 1 = Message ID.
  MessageFile="/dev/fs/C/Users/salasfri/Desktop/Messages.txt"
  Message=$(awk '$1 ~ /^'$MessageID'$/ {$1=""; print $0}' $MessageFile)
}
```

the Message File looks for this in the file "MessageFile":

```
0005                The file ${1} was not tranmitted.
```

it search for 0005 and get the message "The file ${1} was not tranmitted."

I want to replace ${1} with the name of the file

this could be possible with awk? any idea?

Comment: What does `the name of the file` stand for? The `MessageFile`? Any other filename? Which variable holds that `name of the file`?

Comment: To replace a substring in a string you should use `sub()` or `gsub()` functions: `sub("$\{1\}","my filename", $0)`. Bear in mind that `{1}` has a special meaning as an E.R.E. and therefore escape character must be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do...

```
awk '$1~/^'$MessageID'$/ {$1=""; sub("\\${1}",FILENAME); print}'
```

but perhaps you want to change to

```
awk -v mid="${MessageID}" '$1==mid {$1=""; sub("\\${1}",FILENAME); print}'
```

since you're looking for an exact match, not pattern match.  Also better to use awk variables instead of quote dance.